# Como recuperar Extras de uma PendingIntent (Android)?

Tags: android, android-notification, android-intent

Estou implementando Notificações em um app.

Estou usando AlarmManager com uma PendingIntent de uma Intent com dados (no Extras, alguns objetos modelo) mas, quando eu os recebo no em outra class BroadcastReceiver, aqueles extras não estão lá.

aqui está o código:

MainActivity

```
private void saveNotification(Tarefa tarefa) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("tarefa", tarefa); 
    // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); - tentei usar essas flags, mas não funcionou
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 12345678, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "setting the notification in 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
        Tarefa tarefa = (Tarefa) b.getSerializable("tarefa");
        startNotification(context, taskTitle , taskText );
    }
}
```

Meu palpite é que quando eu recebo uma intent no método onReceive, essa intent não é necessáriamente a que foi enviada anteriormente no método saveNotification, minha dúvida é como recuperar esses dados da Intent certa.

**EDIT**

Estou tentando enviar um objeto `Tarefa` que implementa a classe Serializable, mas o objeto retorna null arremessando a NullPointerException. Corrigi o código acima.

Perguntaram sobre o *AndroidManifest.xml* se eu tinha incluído um receiver, segue código:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver ">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Fiz aqui um teste usando esse mesmo código e está funcionando, passando os extras normalmente. Aparece algum erro?

Comment: @AckLay eu também não vejo nada de errado.

Comment: @ramaral tem duas hipóteses, ou o erro está no método no `startNotification()`, que não conseguimos repreoduzir, ou ele não criou o `<receiver>` no AndroidManifest.xml. ^^

Comment: @AckLay se o BroadcastReceiver está a ser chamado é porque foi registado ou no *AndroidManifest.xml* ou através de `Context#registerReceiver()`. Temos de aguardar pelo *feedback* dele.

Comment: @AckLay obrigado pela ajuda, alterei a pergunta e inclui as dúvidas

Comment: @ramaral inclui no Manifesto o receiver, porem continua vindo vazio o objeto